# What is the execution flow of blocks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, objective-c-blocks

I am working with Objective-C blocks, but I'm having troubles understanding the below code execution.

Here is the code :

```
NSArray *array = @[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"A", @"B", @"Z", @"G", @"are", @"Q"];
NSSet *filterSet = [NSSet setWithObjects: @"A", @"Z", @"Q", nil];

BOOL (^test)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop);

test = ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    if (idx < 5) {
        if ([filterSet containsObject: obj]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
};

NSIndexSet *indexes = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:test];
NSLog(@"indexes: %@", indexes);
```

Output:

```
indexes: <NSIndexSet: 0x10236f0>[number of indexes: 2 (in 2 ranges), indexes: (0 3)]
```

In this method, `[array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:test];`, the `test` block is the parameter I passed.

But in the above block, `test = ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)` what are the values of the parameters `obj`, `idx` and `stop` it can take? Where are they from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 9 items in your array. So the `test` block is executed 9 times.
Each time, obj will be the object from the array. And idx will be the index.

First time: obj=@"A" idx=0

Second time: obj=@"B" idx=1

etc.

`stop` is a value you can write to, if you wanted to exit early. So if on the 5th time through the block, you didn't want to do it anymore. you could do `*stop=YES;`

Comment: will idx index values take automatically like idx=0, idx=1 and soon....?

Comment: thank you, i executed just now, it automatically takes above format.. thank your very much....